# Literal '{{transactionTotal}}' appear when using Facebook conversion pixel instead of it being replaced by a number

Tags: facebook, tracking, marketing

I have this as the datalayer. When I view the sourcecode of the site, the datalayer appears at the bottom of the page.

```
dataLayer = [{
    transactionId: '172601',
    transactionTotal: 6.09,
    transactionTax: 0,
    transactionShipping: 0,
    transactionProducts: []
}];


dataLayer[0].transactionProducts.push({
    sku: '297',
    name: 'Time Slot Event - General Admission',
    price: '1.05',
    quantity: 1 
});
```

I created this pixel for importing the transaction total. I removed the pixel id from it just for here. I do have the correct one in the end code.

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '//pixelidhasbeenremoved//');
fbq('track', "PageView");
fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration', {
  content_name: '{{transactionId}}',
  value: '{{transactionTotal}}',
  currency: 'USD'
}); 

</script>

<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=//pixelidhasbeenremoved//&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=//pixelidhasbeenremoved//&ev=CompleteRegistration&amp;cd[value]= {{transactionTotal}}amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1"/>
</noscript>

<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

It is only pulling in {{transactionTotal}} for the price rather than the the variable itself. Anyone know where I am going wrong here? I have created them fine for a few other sites, but this one is just not cooperating.